# NodeJS+TypeScript, mongoose custom interface doesn't extend mongoose.Document properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm relatively new to typescript, so I partially followed this guide: 
http://brianflove.com/2016/11/11/typescript-2-express-mongoose-mocha-chai/

And I ended up with the following code(only the relevant parts):

```
import { Document } from "mongoose";
import { IUser } from "../interfaces/user";

export interface IUserModel extends IUser, Document {
  // custom methods for your model would be defined here
}
```

and:

```
import { IUserModel } from "./models/user";    

let connection: mongoose.Connection = mongoose.createConnection(MONGODB_CONNECTION);
this.model.user = connection.model<IUserModel>('User', userSchema);

var newUser: IUserModel = <IUserModel>{username:'asd',password:'bsd',email:'lol',admin:false};

newUser.save();
```

And according to the editor, it should work, however newUser only has the properties I gave it after compiling.

My setup is pretty much identical with the one in the tutorial.

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my entire approach was wrong.

Creating a newUser with `<IUserModel>{...}` will simply create an object that matches its interface parameters, and nothing else, so in this case an object filled with username, password, etc., and not an actual model instance.

Also it doesn't even relate to the connection above it, which is something I completely missed.

So instead I just had to do the following:

```
var newUser = new this.model.user({ username: 'asd', password: 'bsd', email: 'lol', admin: false });
newUser.save();
```

This creates the proper model instance I wanted.